# Center image in group JavaFX

Tags: javafx-8

I'm trying to make some figures in JavaFX. I can create these figures with the Polygon class or in this case with the Circle class. But I want to add an image on top of it. So I'm using a group for this with 2 elements, the figure and the image in an ImageView. But if I use this group, the image isn't in the middle. I would like to center the image. I also would like to be able to drag and drop it with a mouse, so then it needs to stay in the middle. I've tried it with a circle and a polygon but in both cases the image was in the bottom right corner.

Edit: I just figured out that you can move your image with setX and setY, but this isn't an easy way to center the image.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
public class Figure extends Group {

public Figure() {
    Circle circle = new Circle(100);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        circle.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        Image image = new Image("images/blue/bike.png");
        imageView.setImage(image);
        imageView.setFitWidth(100);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        imageView.setSmooth(true);
        imageView.setCache(true);
        super.getChildren().addAll(circle, imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to use a `StackPane` instead of a `Group`. That might give problems with clickability if you let them overlap: one of two `Circle`s is then obscured by the other figure's `StackPane`.

Though a bit inelegant, I would do it with `setX` and `setY` as you propose.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly the problem with a stackpane. I sometimes place those polygons close to each other and it gives problem with the clickability of the figure. I think it's because a stackpane's clickable space is always a square.